# vb.net filter binding source by time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

hi there i have a database with `date/time` (highlighted in red in the image below) fields and the formatting is `Medium Time` as shown below.

[image]

and the field type and format of `log_in_time` field..

[image]

i've connected the database to my vb.net project and i'm using the following code to filter the binding source with `log_in_time` field of the database. i'm using a `datetimepicker` as the input source. note that `LogoutTime` is the `datetimepicker`
the code..

```
Private Sub LoginTime_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginTime.ValueChanged, LoginTime.KeyPress
    'filter the binding source with the input data
    Try
        '30-Dec-99 is the default date for time
        PaymentdetailsBindingSource.Filter = "log_in_time = '30-Dec-99 " & LoginTime.Text & "'"
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

the format of the `datetimepicker` is set to `custom format` which is `hh:mm tt` now the problem is that the above code does not work, it returns an empty search result.. what could i be doing wrong any help would be appreciated.. thanks..

Comment: someone has to ask the obvious - are you trying to filter log_out... or log_in...? question says log_in.. code log_out...

Comment: the format is just how it is displayed in Access, not how it is stored.

Comment: what do you suggest i do....

Comment: Move the LoginTime value to a Date variable and format as needed for the filter. Check the string you using for the filter. Note that sometimes an exact comparison of time values fails due to rounding/representation issues.

Comment: to be honest i've been googling for days now.. soo i would really appreciate it if you gave me a code sample..

Comment: Have you actually checked what the filter string is? - if the field only contains 10:25 AM and you are trying to filter it with '30-Dec-99 10:25 AM' then it clearly won't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, the issue is probably you are including more (or less) in your filter than is in the field.

If the field contains ONLY `10:25 AM`and  your filter includes the date (so your full filter string is `30-Dec-99 10:25 AM`), this will return no matches OR if the field actually contains seconds as well as the time you would not get a match. 

(in either case with the field formatted as above it would only show `10:25 AM`.

If your field does ONLY contain the time `10:25 AM` then try:

```
PaymentdetailsBindingSource.Filter = "log_in_time = '" & LoginTime.Text & "'"
```